# My node of ROS keeps dying. Subscribe a gazebo topic and publish in a ros topic

Tags: ros, gazebo, nodes, subscribe, publish

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I have created a node in ROS so I can subscribe a  topic of gazebo, analyse the information and then use it.
I have a callback function for the subscription and I put the information in a  certain structure. Then i use that structure to analyse that information and finally I publish the information in a ROS topic.

To keep the information updated I need to clear the structures where I am putting the information . (Probably I need some thread safe procedure)

In main function I have some initializations and the usual while(ros:ok()) cycle. Inside the while i have a gazebo::common::Time::MSleep(50);  and then  ros::spinOnce();

The error messages printed in the screen are:

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
what():  std::bad_alloc
Aborted (core dumped)

or:

(Segmentation fault)

I think this happens because at some point I try to access the structure right after i clear it in the callback function.

Does anyone have some clue of what is happening?

EDIT:
my code is something like that:

```
gazebo_msgs::ContactsState contact_gz_ros_global;

gazebo_msgs::ContactsState updateContactData(){

gazebo_msgs::ContactsState result;
for(int i=0; i< contact_gz_ros_global.states.size() ; i++){
    result.states.push_back(contact_gz_ros_global.states[i]);
}
return result;
}

void cb(ConstContactsPtr &msg){
 //if there is contacts
//contact_gz_ros_global.clear();
//copy info from msg to contac_gz_ros_global structure
}

int main(int _argc, char **_argv)
{
 // Load gazebo
  gazebo::setupClient(_argc, _argv);
   ros::init(_argc, _argv, "gz_subs_tf_pub");
   gazebo::transport::NodePtr node(new gazebo::transport::Node());
   node->Init();
  gazebo::transport::SubscriberPtr sub = node->Subscribe( "~/physics/contacts" , cb);

  ros::NodeHandle n;
  ros::Publisher pub_gz_ros = n.advertise<icub_gazebo::TFVectors>("/gazebo/regrasp/positions_normals",1000);
  ros::Rate loop_rate(1);
  icub_gazebo::TFVectors msg_tf;
  gazebo_msgs::ContactsState contact_gz_ros;

  while (ros::ok()){
     contact_gz_ros =  updateContactData();
     for(int contacts_count=0; contacts_count< contact_gz_ros.states.size();contacts_count++){
             //access information of the contact_gz_ros
      }
      gazebo::common::Time::MSleep(50);
      ros::spinOnce();
  }
  gazebo::shutdown();
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217379/my-node-of-ros-keeps-dying.-subscribe-a-gazebo-topic-and-publish-in-a-ros-topic/) by [anasilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/23812/anasilva/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-09-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anasilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/23812/anasilva/) on 2015-09-10**:
I tried to put: static pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER; pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex); contact_gz_ros =  updateContactData();  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
and  : gazebo::common::Time::MSleep(50); loop_rate.sleep();  ros::spinOnce();
but it does not work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

(You've given a vague question, so the best I can do is a vague answer)

You have a bad memory access somewhere in your program.

It sounds like you have multiple threads, and you're modifying variables from both threads. You should protect any accesses to  shared variables with a mutex or some other thread locking mechanism.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-09-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0